# Replace string path in log file with current folder name

Tags: shell, awk, sed, xargs

I'm new here and already tried to find solution to the following requirement without success. I'm trying to achieve this:

I have these 5 folders:

```
ServiceEngine
PaymentEngine
InvoiceEngine
ProcessEngine
OrderProcessEngine
```

Inside each of these folders, I have a log file with default path location to store the log files e.g. `ServiceEngine/logs`

The log file contain the following path structure:

```
name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="logs/engine.log" 
filePattern="logs/engine-%i.log"
```

I expect to find a way that I retrieve the name of the current folder which I'm in and replace the string engine with folder name

Example: I'm in ServiceEngine folder and execute a command that retrieve the current folder name. The expected result is:

```
name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="logs/ServiceEngine.log" 
filePattern="logs/ServiceEngine-%i.log
```

Later I change the directory to PaymentEngine and the expected result is:

```
name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="logs/PaymentEngine.log" 
filePattern="logs/PaymentEngine-%i.log
```

and so on. Maybe there is a smarter way to create a script that update the string in a loop like do; `if` ... `fi; done` or to use the `for in` ... loop.

Comment: `"logs/PaymentEngine-%i.log` looks like DOS batch syntax. What type of file are the log files?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I would suggest to analyze your log, use `Splunk`.  Its free to use up to 500MB log pr day.  And it will handle files and format automatically.

Comment: @RegExp12 Do you need anything else? If not, please ✓ one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
~/ServiceEngine$ cat logfile
name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="logs/engine.log"
filePattern="logs/engine-%i.log"

~/ServiceEngine$ awk -v path=$(basename $(pwd)) 'gsub("engine", path)' logfile
name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="logs/ServiceEngine.log"
filePattern="logs/ServiceEngine-%i.log"
```

See [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename), [declaring variables in awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html) and [awk gsub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. I have tried the command, but it only print out the result without saving it in the file

Comment: @RegExp12 You probably have gawk when you call awk. Since version 4.1.0 you simply call `awk -i inplace` (check with `awk --version`). Use a temp file for older versions, so `awk ... > logfile_new ; mv logfile_new logfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't understand your question, but:

```
dir=$( basename $( pwd ) )
echo name="RollingRandomAccessFile" \
     fileName="logs/$dir.log" \
     filePattern="logs/$dir-%i.log"
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```
$ sed 's/\bengine\b/'$(basename $(pwd))'/' logs
```

When run from within one of your folders, it spits out the text you're asking for. It wasn't clear what you wanted to **do** with that text though.